# How to increase width and height of plotly area graph

Tags: d3.js, plotly

I don't want to increase height and width of div tag. Just I want increase only following part of graph. I referred [this code](https://plot.ly/javascript/filled-area-plots/)

[image]

My html code is:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

And my plotly.js code is:

```
var trace1 = {
x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-10-06 22:23:00',  '2013-11-04 22:23:00',       '2013-11-07 22:23:00','2013-12-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-08 22:23:00'],
y: [1, 3, 6,2, 4, 5],
fill: 'tozeroy',
type: 'scatter',
fillcolor: 'red'
```

};

```
var plotlyData = [trace1];                                      
plotly.newPlot('heap_memory_graph', plotlyData);
var plotDiv = document.getElementById('heap_memory_graph');

plotDiv.on('plotly_relayout',
 function(eventdata){  
   xValStart = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]']);
   xValEnd = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']);
 });
```

When I putting this graph into my application then graph coming very small.
I tried to increase width and height but I unable to increase this part of graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`margin`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-margin) to `layout` and specify the distance (in pixels) of the graph from the surrounding box.

```js
var trace1 = {
x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-10-06 22:23:00',  '2013-11-04 22:23:00',       '2013-11-07 22:23:00','2013-12-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-08 22:23:00'],
y: [1, 3, 6,2, 4, 5],
fill: 'tozeroy',
type: 'scatter',
fillcolor: 'red'
};
var layout = {
  margin: {
    l: 20,
    r: 10,
    b: 40,
    t: 10
  },
};

var plotlyData = [trace1];                                      
Plotly.newPlot('heap_memory_graph', plotlyData, layout);
var plotDiv = document.getElementById('heap_memory_graph');
```

```html
  
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<div id="heap_memory_graph" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's looking nice in my application.

Comment: can you give me solution for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472453/why-graph-is-getting-blank-after-dragging-it