# Why plotly area graph is not displaying data properly?

Tags: javascript, plotly

Data is coming from beck end correctly but on graph is not displaying properly sometimes. Why its happening sometimes? I referred [this code.](https://plot.ly/javascript/filled-area-plots/)

Area of graph not filling properly. My graph is looking like this some time:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
<script>
var abc = ['2013-10-04 02:23:00', '2013-10-22 12:23:00',  '2013-11-04 20:23:00', '2013-11-020 10:23:00','2013-12-04 15:10:45', '2013-12-26 06:03:00'];
abc[6]='2014-05-02 20:23:00';
var trace1 = {
x: abc,
y: [1, 3, 6,9, 4, 5,8],
  fill: 'tozeroy',
  fillcolor: 'red',
  text: server1,
  hoverinfo: "x+y+text",
  type: 'scatter',
  mode:"markers",
  marker:
  {
    size:4,
    color:"gray"
  },
  uid:"c2e171",
  dragmode:"turntable"
};
var layout = {
  margin: {
    l: 35,
    r: 40,
    b: 50,
    t: 10
  },
  legend: {
    "orientation": "h"
  },
  xaxis: {
    showgrid: false,
    showline: true,
    ticks: "outside"
  },
  yaxis : {
    fixedrange: true,
    showgrid: false,
    showline: true,
    ticks: "outside"
  },
  dragmode:false,
};
var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data,layout, {modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['sendDataToCloud','hoverCompareCartesian','zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','autoScale2d','hoverClosestCartesian','toggleSpikelines']});

var plotDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
plotDiv.on('plotly_relayout',
function(eventdata){  
    alert( 'ZOOM!' + '\n\n' +
        'Event data:' + '\n' + 
         JSON.stringify(eventdata) + '\n\n' +
        'x-axis start:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]'])+ '\n' +
        'x-axis end:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']));
        var xVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]']);
        var yVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']);
});

</script>
</body>
```

I'm getting data for x and y dynamically from backend. Don't consider above x and y data.

I'm getting following data for x and y from backend:
date for x
and value for Y

```
{
 "results": [
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:57:48",
   "value": 302
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:58:18",
   "value": 329
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:58:48",
   "value": 344
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:59:18",
   "value": 372
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:59:48",
   "value": 391
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:00:18",
   "value": 428
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:00:48",
   "value": 445
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:01:18",
   "value": 287
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:01:48",
   "value": 302
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:02:18",
   "value": 331
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:02:48",
   "value": 346
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:03:18",
   "value": 374
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:03:48",
   "value": 388
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:04:18",
   "value": 417
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:04:48",
   "value": 433
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:05:18",
   "value": 461
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:05:48",
   "value": 474
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:06:18",
   "value": 316
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:06:48",
   "value": 330
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:07:18",
   "value": 357
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:07:48",
   "value": 374
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:08:18",
   "value": 402
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:08:48",
   "value": 415
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:09:18",
   "value": 443
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:09:48",
   "value": 460
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:10:18",
   "value": 301
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:10:48",
   "value": 314
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:11:18",
   "value": 344
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:11:48",
   "value": 359
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:12:18",
   "value": 385
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:12:48",
   "value": 400
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:13:18",
   "value": 429
  },
  { 
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:13:48",
   "value": 444
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:14:18",
   "value": 470
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:14:48",
   "value": 301
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:15:18",
   "value": 331
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:15:48",
   "value": 346
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:16:18",
   "value": 373
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:16:48",
   "value": 425
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:17:18",
   "value": 453
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:17:48",
   "value": 468
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:18:18",
   "value": 307
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:18:48",
   "value": 322
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:19:18",
   "value": 350
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:19:48",
   "value": 365
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:20:18",
   "value": 393
  }, 
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:20:48",
   "value": 408
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:21:18",
   "value": 436
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:21:48",
   "value": 449
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:22:18",
   "value": 291
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:22:48",
   "value": 306
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:23:18",
   "value": 333
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:23:48",
   "value": 346
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:24:18",
   "value": 375
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:24:48",
   "value": 392
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:25:18",
   "value": 419
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:25:48",
   "value": 434
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:26:18",
   "value": 462
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:26:48",
   "value": 476
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:27:18",
   "value": 317
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:27:48",
   "value": 332
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:28:18",
   "value": 359
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:28:48",
   "value": 374
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:29:18",
   "value": 406
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:29:48",
   "value": 421
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:30:18",
   "value": 449
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:30:48",
   "value": 463
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:31:18",
   "value": 305
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:31:48",
   "value": 319
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:32:18",
   "value": 346
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:32:48",
   "value": 361
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:33:18",
   "value": 389
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:33:48",
   "value": 404
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:34:18",
   "value": 433
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:34:48",
   "value": 447
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:35:18",
  "value": 476
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:35:48",
   "value": 303
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:36:18",
   "value": 331
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:36:48",
   "value": 347
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:37:18",
   "value": 374
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:37:48",
   "value": 389
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:38:18",
   "value": 416
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:38:48",
   "value": 432
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:39:18",
   "value": 461
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:39:48",
   "value": 475
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:40:18",
   "value": 318
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:40:48",
   "value": 332
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:41:18",
   "value": 360
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:41:48",
   "value": 373
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:42:18",
   "value": 403
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:42:48",
   "value": 418
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:43:18",
   "value": 446
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:43:48",
   "value": 459
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:44:18",
   "value": 305
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:44:48",
   "value": 320
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:45:18",
   "value": 347
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:45:48",
   "value": 364
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:46:18",
   "value": 391
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:46:48",
   "value": 444
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:47:18",
   "value": 475
  }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: I don't use plotly, so making this a comment so it might (or maybe not) lead you to the answer.  I use d3 standalone, and when I first started, I got graphs that looked like this when I set fill on the line instead of creating an area.  In vanilla d3 it's similar to a line declaration, var area = d3.area().curve(d3.curveMonotoneX).x.....etc.  But for sure that's what a filled line looks like in d3, not a filled area.

Comment: @Aaron, Thank you for your valuable response. Please don't consider above x and y value. I kept here to understand code. Can you suggest me why its happening?

Comment: will d3 code help you?  I can't help with the plotly part.  I can put together a quick and dirty graph that switches between an area and filled line though if you think it'll help?

Comment: @Aaron, please put your graph together. May be I will get some idea.

Comment: Ok, I just had a production issue come up.  It'll be a bit but I'll get back today.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a variable _server1_ defined before the variable _trace1_? There is reference to _server1_ in the property `trace1.y` (i.e `y: [1, 3, 6,9, 4, 5,8],
  fill: 'tozeroy',
  fillcolor: 'red',
  text: server1,`...

Comment: @Sam Onela, Please don't consider server1. I updated my question

Comment: You may have removed the property _name_ (i.e. `name:"Server 1",`) but in that code snippet there is still a reference to an **undefined variable** _server1_ 2 lines above that...

Comment: @AnilJagtap I can't get this to work in jsfiddle - cross origin and loading the csv are taking too much time for me to figure out to make it worth figuring them out right now (I'm having production issues today)...Here is a video that shows what I would have shown on a fiddle - if you want the code, I can message it to you, or add an answer (Hesitant to add an answer, it's not technically an answer for plotly...) ..  But, it looks like your issue already has an answer, so this is just to show area/line fill differences. https://www.dropbox.com/s/855w08k37ci2h3j/2017-04-19-1226-14.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine in this code.  I got an error that server1 was not defined, but otherwise it seems to work as expected.  My initial thought was that something was off with your x axis, but everything seem to render fine here.  What version of d3 are you using?  Also, what browser?  I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu.

[image]

**Update:**
I added the updated data.  There was a missing comma near the date "2017-04-06 00:44:18" that was causing some problems parsing it.  I fixed that, but am able to render it all with the same code as before.  The new chart looks like this:

[image]

I'm still not able to reproduce your rendering error, but I'll see if I can do it by playing with margin.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>  
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
<script>




var realData = {
 "results": [
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:57:48",
   "value": 302
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:58:18",
   "value": 329
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:58:48",
   "value": 344
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:59:18",
   "value": 372
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 11:59:48",
   "value": 391
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:00:18",
   "value": 428
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:00:48",
   "value": 445
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:01:18",
   "value": 287
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:01:48",
   "value": 302
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:02:18",
   "value": 331
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:02:48",
   "value": 346
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:03:18",
   "value": 374
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:03:48",
   "value": 388
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:04:18",
   "value": 417
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:04:48",
   "value": 433
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:05:18",
   "value": 461
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:05:48",
   "value": 474
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:06:18",
   "value": 316
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:06:48",
   "value": 330
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:07:18",
   "value": 357
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:07:48",
   "value": 374
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:08:18",
   "value": 402
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:08:48",
   "value": 415
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:09:18",
   "value": 443
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:09:48",
   "value": 460
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:10:18",
   "value": 301
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:10:48",
   "value": 314
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:11:18",
   "value": 344
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:11:48",
   "value": 359
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:12:18",
   "value": 385
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:12:48",
   "value": 400
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:13:18",
   "value": 429
  },
  { 
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:13:48",
   "value": 444
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:14:18",
   "value": 470
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:14:48",
   "value": 301
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:15:18",
   "value": 331
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:15:48",
   "value": 346
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:16:18",
   "value": 373
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:16:48",
   "value": 425
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:17:18",
   "value": 453
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:17:48",
   "value": 468
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:18:18",
   "value": 307
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:18:48",
   "value": 322
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:19:18",
   "value": 350
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:19:48",
   "value": 365
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:20:18",
   "value": 393
  }, 
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:20:48",
   "value": 408
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:21:18",
   "value": 436
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:21:48",
   "value": 449
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:22:18",
   "value": 291
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:22:48",
   "value": 306
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:23:18",
   "value": 333
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:23:48",
   "value": 346
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:24:18",
   "value": 375
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:24:48",
   "value": 392
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:25:18",
   "value": 419
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:25:48",
   "value": 434
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:26:18",
   "value": 462
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:26:48",
   "value": 476
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:27:18",
   "value": 317
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:27:48",
   "value": 332
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:28:18",
   "value": 359
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:28:48",
   "value": 374
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:29:18",
   "value": 406
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:29:48",
   "value": 421
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:30:18",
   "value": 449
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:30:48",
   "value": 463
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:31:18",
   "value": 305
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:31:48",
   "value": 319
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:32:18",
   "value": 346
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:32:48",
   "value": 361
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:33:18",
   "value": 389
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:33:48",
   "value": 404
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:34:18",
   "value": 433
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:34:48",
   "value": 447
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:35:18",
  "value": 476
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:35:48",
   "value": 303
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:36:18",
   "value": 331
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:36:48",
   "value": 347
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:37:18",
   "value": 374
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:37:48",
   "value": 389
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:38:18",
   "value": 416
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:38:48",
   "value": 432
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:39:18",
   "value": 461
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:39:48",
   "value": 475
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:40:18",
   "value": 318
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:40:48",
   "value": 332
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:41:18",
   "value": 360
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:41:48",
   "value": 373
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:42:18",
   "value": 403
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:42:48",
   "value": 418
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:43:18",
   "value": 446
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:43:48",
   "value": 459
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:44:18",
   "value": 305
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:44:48",
   "value": 320
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:45:18",
   "value": 347
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:45:48",
   "value": 364
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:46:18",
   "value": 391
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:46:48",
   "value": 444
  },
  {
   "date": "2017-04-06 00:47:18",
   "value": 475
  }
 ]
 }

var abc = ['2013-10-04 02:23:00', '2013-10-22 12:23:00',  '2013-11-04 20:23:00', '2013-11-020 10:23:00','2013-12-04 15:10:45', '2013-12-26 06:03:00'];
abc[6]='2014-05-02 20:23:00';

var dates = [];
var vals = [];
realData.results.forEach( function(m) { dates.push(m.date); vals.push(m.value);});

var trace1 = {
x: dates,
y: vals,
  fill: 'tozeroy',
  fillcolor: 'red',
  text: "server1",
  hoverinfo: "x+y+text",
  name:"Server 1",
  type: 'scatter',
  mode:"markers",
  marker:
  {
    size:4,
    color:"gray"
  },
  uid:"c2e171",
  dragmode:"turntable"
};
var layout = {
  margin: {
    l: 35,
    r: 40,
    b: 50,
    t: 10
  },
  legend: {
    "orientation": "h"
  },
  xaxis: {
    showgrid: false,
    showline: true,
    ticks: "outside"
  },
  yaxis : {
    fixedrange: true,
    showgrid: false,
    showline: true,
    ticks: "outside"
  },
  dragmode:false,
};
var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data,layout, {modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['sendDataToCloud','hoverCompareCartesian','zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','autoScale2d','hoverClosestCartesian','toggleSpikelines']});

var plotDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
plotDiv.on('plotly_relayout',
function(eventdata){  
    alert( 'ZOOM!' + '\n\n' +
        'Event data:' + '\n' + 
         JSON.stringify(eventdata) + '\n\n' +
        'x-axis start:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]'])+ '\n' +
        'x-axis end:' + new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']));
        var xVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[0]']);
        var yVal = new Date(eventdata['xaxis.range[1]']);
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response. Please don't consider above x and y value. I kept here to understand code. Can you suggest me why its happening?

Comment: I'm using chrome on windows and I'm using following: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

Comment: if possible help me for this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472453/why-graph-is-getting-blank-after-dragging-it

Comment: I changed the plotly code to the source you're using, but my example isn't using JQuery at all.  It still seems to work fine.

Comment: It would be hard to diagnose without seeing the actual code.  My guess is that maybe you have a negative value somewhere, either in your margins or your data.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question "_Why its happening sometimes?_"

Comment: @SamOnela - it's hard to know "Why is it happening" without seeing the data.  The first thing I was trying to establish is that it's not happening with the code provided.  In my last comment, I tried to give the best guess, and say that I need to have actual data to really troubleshoot it further.

Comment: @nixkuroi, I added my actual data for x and y which is coming from backend.

Comment: Are there a lot of other things on the page?  Maybe it's rendering before all items are on the page, then the container is resizing smaller than the plot?

Comment: @nixkuroi, there in not any other things. Still getting graph like above.

Comment: I noticed your plot is differently styled.  Could you put all the code in for your plot?